# Weka classifier new class attribute : arrayOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, matlab, weka

I have a dataset like this;

numeric_attr1, numeric_attr2, ... , numeric_attrN, string_attr, class_attr

The string_attr is a list of image filenames that are used to create cross-validation folds so that there is no obs. from one image in both test and training sets. (The attribute is then deleted, and is not the issue here).

There are 6 classes: {A, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5}

I am trying to create a new class attribute: {A, B}, where all the B1, B2, etc are converted to 'B'.

(I work in Matlab, but call weka methods through it, so the notation below is a mix of pseudo/matlab/java --- sorry !)

**Method 1: Rename the attribute values**

```
dataset.renameAttributeValue(class_attr, 'B1', 'B') 
dataset.renameAttributeValue(class_attr, 'B', 'B') 
.
.
.
```

Does not work, as the class values end up : {A, B, B, B, B, B}, with a similar 6x6 confusion matrix that throws off the accuracy rates. (I could manually shift the rows and columns of the matrix after classification but that's messy).

**Method 2: Create a new attribute**

```
% Create new attribute
newAttribute = Attribute('label', FastVector('A', 'B'))
% Insert it at end of dataset
dataset.insertAttributeAt(newAttribute, dataset.numAttributes())

% Rename old attribute values to the new ones 
dataset.renameAttributeValue(class_attr, 'B1', 'B') 
% .. etc

% Loop over each instance and assign the (converted) old attribute value to the new attribute
for i .. dataset.numInstances
    oldValue = dataset.instance(i).classValue; % Which is now replaced with {TIS,CAN}
    D.instance(i).setValue(newClassIndex, oldValue);
end

% Set class to newClassIndex, delete attribute at oldClassIndex
dataset.setClass(dataset.attribute(newClassIndex));
dataset.deleteAttributeAt(oldClassIndex);
```

Does not work. When I try to train a classifier I get:

```
??? Java exception occurred:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at weka.classifiers.trees.RandomTree.buildClassifier(RandomTree.java:595)
    at weka.classifiers.meta.Bagging.buildClassifier(Bagging.java:529)
    at weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest.buildClassifier(RandomForest.java:517)
```

**Method 3: Manually replace values in ARFF file**

If I open up the arff file in VIM and use a regex to replace all the B1..B5 with 'B', I get a file that I can open, split into folds and train/test a classifier on.

The regex'd file has the exact same attributes as the original, including the string_attr used to create the folds which is then deleted.

Checking the class attribute and class index of the regex'd file and the attributeAdded file show the same class index, and same class attribute values:

```
dataset2.classIndex % The file that had was manually changed
>> 179
dataset2.classAttribute
>> @attribute nlabel {A,B} % Has a different label name, but this happens before test/train splitting

dataset1.classIndex % The original file that had a new attribute added
>> 179
dataset1.classAttribute
>> @attribute label {A,B}
```

I would really rather be able to do this using the set Weka methods, rather than a script to parse the ARFF file and replace values.

**--**

**So I guess my question is:** can anyone suggest a better way to convert the class values, or does anyone know where/how the arrayoutofboundsexception occurs?

Many thanks.

Comment: Regarding method 2: before you build the classifier, have you tried outputting the instances (including the new attribute) as a ".arff"?  I suspect there may be some inconsistency between the header of the ".arff" and its contents (especially for the last attribute).  If this is the case you may see some way to improve your code.

Comment: I tried writing the arff to disk but was getting a similar ArrayOutofBounds exception. I suspect it may be an extension of the problem in method 1: that the renamed values are displayed the same (i.e. {A,B,B,B,B,B}) but are different under the hood. Will post back soon!

Comment: As a followup; the problem was indeed that the renamed class values still had different factor indices, despite having the same class string values. The solution was to map the renamed class value factor indices to the new one. I.e. Create a new attribute with the required class values {A,B}, then map the indices of the old class value to the new one: {A,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5} with factor indices {0,1,2,3,4,5} -> map all values 1,2,3,4,5 -> 1 when assigning the value of the new attribute.